# Difference between helm-occur and helm-swoop?

Tags: helm

helm swoop seems slow sometimes.

I'm trying helm occur, and wonder what's the difference.
They look very similar.

I'm asking because I'm afraid I'm missing a point that the library is trying to address.
Since I'm switching mainly due to speed.

Comment: One question per post, please. Post your other question separately. Thx.

Comment: will do, thanks